# How to change css class for multiple DOM elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change class property of an DOM element (specifically, for label tag) using jQuery 1.10.2.

Here is my code:

```js
var MyNameSpace = MyNameSpace || {};
MyNameSpace.enableDisableLabels = (function() {
  var m_labelIds = {
    "bookId": "book",
    "customerId": "customer"
  };

  var mf_getjQueryDOMObjectReperesentation = function(arrayObjIds) {
    var result = {};
    $.each(arrayObjIds, function(id, value) {
      result[id] = $("#" + value);
    });
    return result;
  };

  var mf_unBoldLabels = function(arrayjQueryObjLabels) {
    $.each(arrayjQueryObjLabels, function(id, value) {
      value.atrr("class", "outputLabelOpt"); // PROBLEM: TypeError: value.atrr is not a function
    });
  };

  var arrayjQueryObjLabels = mf_getjQueryDOMObjectReperesentation(m_labelIds);
  mf_unBoldLabels(arrayjQueryObjLabels);

}());
```

```css
.outputLabelOpt {
  color: #0B63CA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <label id="book" style="font-weight:bold">book</label>
  <label id="customer" style="font-weight:bold">customer</label>
</body>
```

But I get an error:
TypeError: value.atrr is not a function

Can you please advise what am I doing wrong and how to do it correctly.
Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
mismas

Comment: You have a typo; it's `attr()`, not `atrr()`.

Comment: I don't understand why was I down voted for this question? It is all my work. The problem was typo error, but the question could maybe help someone (beginner) as an example how to chnage css class for multiple DOM elements with jQuery. I don't quite understand what exactly is so much against the rules here? Please explain yourself ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a typo : it is not `atrr`, but `attr` ;-)

Comment: Thnak you so much! My eyes are weary today :)

Comment: I don't understand why was I down voted for this question?

Answer (score 1):

This is `value.attr` not `.atrr`.

For `class` attribute manipulation, you also have `.addClass("classname")` and `.removeClass("classname")`.

Comment: Actually, here, the values of the array are really jQuery objects :
`result[id] = $("#" + value);`, so this not the problem ;-)